# Probability that 1 and 2 are in their proper place but 3 and 4 are not

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Seven digits $(1-7)$ must be arranged.
$A_i$ is the event that the $i\text{th}$ digit is in the $i\text{th}$ place. B is the event that 1 and 2 are both in their proper places but 3 and 4 are both in the wrong places. What is the probability of event B? $$ B= A_1A_2A_3^cA_4^c$$
I know that: $$ P(A_1A_2...A_n)=\frac{1}{n!}$$
But how do I take $A_3^CA_4^C$ into consideration?

Comment: Do you know how to use the principle of inclusion and exclusion?

Comment: @RobertShore I am familiar with it

Comment: Use it to answer this question.  Figure out how many permutations that fix $1$ and $2$ also fix $3$, and how many also fix $4$.  Use the principle to complete the calculation by making sure you don’t double-count.

Comment: Can I also do $P(B)=\frac{n(B)}{n(\Omega}$ where $n(B)=(1)(1)(4)(4)(3!)$?

Comment: I don’t understand how you’re calculating $n(B)$, but when you get it you’ll divide it by $7!$ to get the probability.  I get the probability to be $\frac{78}{5040}=\frac{13}{840}$.

Comment: I tried to do it wherein there is only $(1)$ way to get the 1st correct, $(1)$ way to get the second correct, $(4)^2$ options for the 3rd and 4th then the rest can be chosen in $(3!)$ ways. How do I "fix 1 and 2," etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do direct counting, avoiding principle of inclusion-exclusion.

We have to fill seven slots such that $1,2$ are to stay in their own places. This is done in $1$ way.

$$\underline{1} \; \underline{2} \; \square \; \square \;\square \;\square \;\square \;$$

$3,4$ do not remain in their own place. There are two cases:

- $3$ can go to $4$th spot when $4$ has $4$ available spots.
  $$\underline{1} \; \underline{2} \; \square \; \underline{3} \;\square \;\square \;\square \;$$ There are $1\times 4=4$ ways.
- $3$ does not go to $4$th spot. It goes to one of remaining three places ($5,6,7$) when $4$ has only $3$ available spots.
  $$\underline{1} \; \underline{2} \; \square \; \square \;\underline{3} \;\square \;\square \;$$ There are $3\times 3=9$ ways.

Last three digits can be arranged in $3!$ ways. Count of favorable numbers is
$$1 \cdot (4+9) \cdot 3! = 78$$

Hence required probability is $\dfrac{78}{7!}$.